# Invalid Pure Specifier

Tags: c++

I am currently working on an assignment that asks us to create a Linked List.
This requires us to create pointer to nodes. Those nodes contain values as well as pointers to previous and next nodes. That way, we can navigate the list easily and allocate memory dynamically.
The platform on which I need to submit the assignment (ZyBooks) has a class implemented called "leaker.h" which detects any leaked memory. I am now unable to submit my work because I get this strange error:

In file included from LinkedList.h:4:0,
from main.cpp:5:
leaker.h:95:28: error: invalid pure specifier (only ‘= 0’ is allowed) before ‘=’ token
#define delete _leaker_file=**FILE**, _leaker_func=**func**,

The error shows up whenever I call my constructors (any of them) and a function called Clear().

```
LinkedList()
{
    nodeCount = 0;
    headPtr = nullptr;
    tailPtr = nullptr;
}
//Copy Constructor
LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& list)
{
    nodeCount = list.nodeCount;
    headPtr = new Node(list.headPtr->data);
    Node* tempNode = list.headPtr->next;
    Node* outNode = headPtr->next;
    Node* prevNode = headPtr;
    while (tempNode != nullptr)
    { 
        outNode = new Node(tempNode->data);
        prevNode->next = outNode;
        outNode->prev = prevNode;
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
        outNode = outNode->next;
        prevNode = prevNode->next;
    }
    tailPtr = prevNode;
    tailPtr->prev = prevNode->prev;
}
//Brackets Operator
T& operator[](unsigned int index)
{
    try {
        if (index < 0 || index >= nodeCount) throw 1;
    }
    catch (int e) {
        cout << "Error: Index Out of Range"<< endl;
    }
    Node* tempNode = headPtr;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (tempNode != nullptr)
    {
        if (i == index) return tempNode->data;
        i++;
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
    }   
    return tempNode->data;
}
//== Operator
bool operator==(const LinkedList<T>& rhs) const
{
    if (nodeCount != rhs.nodeCount) return false;
    Node* tempNode = headPtr;
    Node* otherNode = rhs.headPtr;
    while (tempNode != nullptr)
    {
        if (tempNode->data != otherNode->data) return false;
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
        otherNode = otherNode->next;
    }
    return true;
}
//= Operator
LinkedList<T>& operator=(const LinkedList<T>& rhs)
{
    Node* tempNode = rhs.headPtr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rhs.nodeCount; i++)
    {
        AddTail(tempNode->data);
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
    }
    return *this;
}
//Destructor
~LinkedList()
{
   Node* tempNode = headPtr->next;
   Node* prevNode = headPtr;
   while(prevNode != nullptr)
   {
      delete prevNode;
      prevNode = tempNode;
      tempNode = tempNode->next;
   }
   delete prevNode;
   delete tempNode;
}
```

Sorry for the huge lines of code. I don't know where the error comes from so I thought I'd be better for me to paste all code linked to the error.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code before asking here. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `nodeCount = 0;` makes me wonder : does C++ have type inference ? From what you've given here, not sure we can do anything : no full code and includes, no compiler versions and options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the functions here. There is some macro somewhere (`#define delete _leaker_file=FILE, _leaker_func=func`) which breaks stuff.

The error comes from `leaker.h:95:28` (`leaker.h`, line 95, column 28). I guess you have a deleted function there:

```
leaker(const leaker&) = delete;
```

Will be translated to:

```
 leaker(const leaker&) = _leaker_file=FILE, _leaker_func=func;
```

And compiler has no idea how to proceed.

## If this is your macro, remove it immidiately from code. It's always going to bring you woe and misery.

If it is imported from any other file, don't `#include` that file and you should really reconsider using that library - if it uses such mechanisms, it cannot be a good library - it's Undefined Behaviour to override keywords with macros.

If you cannot find this macro, try commenting out every `#include` from your header, until the problem goes away. You can comment out your current class and make some dummy class to focus on the problem:

```
//#include <vector>
#include <...>

class A {
     A() = delete;
};

//class leaker {
//...
//};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, "leaker.h" is a file that my professor added to recognize any memory leaks. I can't even edit it. When I comment out #include "leaker.h", ZyBooks just gives me no output. No errors either which is weird besides for the Clear() method where I get the following error:
LEAKER: unknown:unknown():0 delete error: pointer was not allocated!
I am really confused :/

Comment: @Bilouge Hmm. I see now why someone decided to macro `delete` keyword, although it's still the worst way to perform such thing. If you cannot edit `leaker.h`, then this problem is impossible to solve on your side - you have to ask your professor to either change his way of detecting memory leaks (there are many great tools which can detect leaks without modyfing code, e.g. `valgrind`) or to not use `delete` for class functions.

Comment: Thanks again for you time. I really appreciate it. Do you think that it may just be that I shouldn't use delete? In which case it would be weird because I always assumed you would need it for the class destructor. It may be that I've mishandled the delete keyword but I don't see how. Anyways... imma try to get an explanation from the professor. Have a good day.

Comment: @Bilouge No, you *should* use `delete`. But `delete` keyword has two menings starting from C++11 - it can be used to deallocate memory (the way you use it) and it can be used to tell compiler to disallow usage of certain functions (mainly copy/move constructors, but not only that). In this case, the syntax is as follows: `A() = delete;`. If someone defines a macro that changes `delete` into something that can measure it's first usage (deallocating), then it cannot possibly make sense in the context of deleted functions.

Comment: Perhaps your professor simply made a mistake in defining the macro too early and simply didn't notice the problem? Or he forgot that he shouldn't use deleted functions together with this macro? In any case, I believe that if `leaker.h` has to be included in your code and if the errors occur in this file, then you have to contact the owner of this file (i.e. your professor). Everyone makes mistakes :)

Comment: I know that everyone mistakes. I just hope he won't try to blame me for said mistake. Thank you very much for your time Yksisarvinen. Have a wonderful day.